# Rewrite Rule for api calls

Tags: regex, apache, api, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i know many others asked questions to clarify how to use RewriteRules and Conditions, and i read many posts here and on other sites and tried to get it work on my own, but i didnt get it work.

When the user calls a url like this

```
https://example.com/api/[EXTENSION]/[SERVICE_NAME]?params
```

internally this url should be called

```
https://example.com/index.php?eID=apiService=[EXTENSION_KEY]/[SERVICE_NAME]&params
```

the params may contain slashes

how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^api/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?eID=api&Service=$1/$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```